# Provide more information for vandalism flags

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, flags, vandalism

The current vandalism flag contains a list containing a sampling of posts relating to the flag

[image]

In order to make it easier to determine *how* much vandalism is going on, I would suggest the following changes be made to the message:

1. Replace "multiple" with the number of incidents at the time of the flag
2. Shorten the links so that more will fit

   - Replace the link title with a number

[image]

Comment: ummm, so what about that fifth one?

Comment: This would be an incredibly useful change, and I thought it had been brought up before (possibly as "please show in the reverse order that you guys do now" and possibly by me for flags in general)

Comment: @jcolebrand: See how confusing and jumbled that flag is?  its all like *WERDS WERDS WERDS*

Comment: The flag isn't tripped well before 20 edits? I assumed that the flag was showing all the edited posts at the time it was created

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: The thing is, I dunno.  The flag isn't exactly informative.

Comment: I remember getting edit-banned for the rest of a day after 5 edits. Not sure about deletions, though.