# Vandalism flags should only be manually dismissed

Tags: bug, flags, vandalism

We have this weird situation where a user is deleting their posts for the past couple of days. That's fine. Whenever a user goes on self-delete mode, the system flags one of the other posts with links to the deleted posts.

And the flag looks something like this:

[image]

<sub>Image credit: [Provide more information for vandalism flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118167/provide-more-information-for-vandalism-flags)</sub>

Here's where things got messier. The user is still on the self-delete mode and deleted the post that contained the flag. This deletion actually dismissed the vandalism flag without any mod intervention.

I don't suppose that is intended. For this particular case, 4 such vandalism flags have been dismissed that way which doesn't allow the mods to grasp the extent of the issue.

Can we not allow vandalism flags from getting dismissed without human intervention?

Comment: Just curious, how you see those flags with no diamond and less than 1000 rep on Stack Overflow?

Comment: I borrowed the image from [Won't's request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118167/provide-more-information-for-vandalism-flags)

Comment: @ShaWiz and also he's a mod on Ask Ubuntu

Comment: Was the flag raised on a previous day? Usually the flag is triggered on a post just as a user is attempting to delete that post, while the user gets blocked from deleting anything for the rest of the day, so the flag will remain for at least a day before the user gets another chance to delete that post.

Comment: @BoltClock We let the flag sit for around a day only to notice it gets replaced by a newer flag. I assumed some other mod handled it but that's apparently not the case. Repeat that 4 times and we are here.

Comment: @Doorknob I know, but he posted examples from SO where he's not. Got me scared for a bit! ;)

Comment: This just came up again: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201767/user-seems-to-edit-and-flag-own-questions-for-deletions